# Find a User by name quickly

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashtable

I have a C++ server that manages Users for a game. These Users have unique AccountIDs and almost every look-up for Users on the server involves finding a User from a global map of

```
std::map<unsigned int, User*>
```

where unsigned int is the AccountID. This works great except for this new case where I am implementing a friends list. In order to add a friend to someones friend list it needs to be done by Username. I am also running into this problem when inviting people by Username to a chatroom or other "party" type events.

My two current options are:

1) Iterate through the entire Users map, doing a string comparison by Username.

2) Do a database look-up on an indexed Username column and return the AccountID, then do a map find for the User*.

Both of these solutions are very inefficient. I am looking for a more optimized solution of finding a User by Username.

The first idea that comes to mind is a Hashtable that hashes on the Username, but then I have two different data structures (the Hashtable and the Map) that are doing the same thing except one is by AccountID and one is by name.

A second option could be to use the Username as the key for the map, although I can't imagine having a string for a key being too efficient.

Any suggestions on what I should do here? As for some more information on the server, there will be around 1000+ Users and they will be leaving and joining constantly.

Answer (score 4):

C++11 has `std::unordered_map` which will automagically handle hashing for you, e.g. `std::unordered_map<std::string, User*>`.

Comment: std::unordered_map is the STL's hash table right? From what I think I know, a hash table will be near constant lookup time (assuming a good hash with few collisions, not sure how good the built in hash function is) while a std::map will be log(n) time. I suppose this is a more optimal solution assuming the hash table is well balanced, and also solves my lookup by username problem.

Comment: As a follow up, a worst case hash table can be O(n) (all elements collide), how can I be sure that I get a well balanced hash table from random usernames?

Comment: You can't be sure, but if the hash method is reasonable, the worst case is so improbable, that you really don't have to care about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using another map `std::map<std::string, User*>`. I believe that for an application with ~1000 users it is over-engineering to do hashmaps or more complicated solutions, the string based lookup in map will not be that expensive, practically zero compared to lookup in database.

Maybe, you can use the by-product of having alphabetically sorted users somewhere as well.

Comment: 1000 Users is the current use case and it is going to expand a lot. Probably to around 10k users. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Lets say you would have 100k users, the lookup is O(log(n)) comparisons of strings, so you can expect something between 13-14 comparisons to get the user from the map. I would personally just do it this way, and if it ever becomes the bottleneck of performance, I would change it to something other. Personally I doubt it would happen.